# Meteor - IE11 displays a blank page

Tags: javascript, meteor, internet-explorer-11, reify

I get this error under IE11:

object doesn't support this property or method "for" on line:

```
var esSymKey = useSymbol ? Symbol.for(esStrKey) : null;
```

from node_modules/meteor/modules/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/utils.js
in modules.js.

I tried to update everything but with no luck

My packages list is as follow:

```
meteor-base

mobile-experience
mongo
blaze-html-templates 
session     
jquery@1.11.10  
tracker
es5-shim

coffeescript
msavin:mongol
tap:i18n
tap:i18n-db-modified
globalconstants
reywood:publish-composite
fourseven:scss
reactive-var
mystor:device-detection
subs-manager-modified
fastclick
check
manuelschoebel:ms-seo-modified
mrt:modernizr-meteor
gorillastack:iron-router-gtm
iron:router
standard-minifier-css
standard-minifier-js
add-scripts
tap:i18n-bundler
shell-server
dynamic-import
webapp

chrome-spiderable
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you solve it?

Comment: I added   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>
in head.html. Not the best solution I assume but any other solution wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks so much! it works for me

Comment: I got this error once because I was embedding the YouTube Embed API in the `/client/header.html` file of my app. Loaded it using `$.getScript` inside `/startup/client/cdn_scripts.js` and it fixed the blank page issue. Turns out the loaded script had an error in it in IE11 which loading it the first way blank screens the entire app.

Answer (score 2):

IE 11 doesn't support `Symbol`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol

You will need to add a polyfill to add support for it.

https://github.com/medikoo/es6-symbol

If you're using other es6+ features, you will probably run into another error immediately after polyfilling `Symbol`. You should probably use some kind of transpiler, like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). It will ensure your new code works on old browsers.

Comment: This is certainly the problem. I have babel-polyfill installed and doing a require('babel-polyfill') at the top of main.js, but getting the same problem. This certain error is in the Meteor Reify core: node_modules/meteor/modules/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/utils.js   I can't load the polyfill before this happens.

Comment: Update: I saw the trick above to do a <script src=babel-polyfill...> in the header. This is the only way to inject it in time before Meteor core.